# Shot in the dark: Is there an english translation of Deligne-Rapoport "Les schemas de modules..." anywhere?

Tags: reference-request, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Extensive googling (and searching here) has yielded nothing, unfortunately.

I knew a language genius once who offered to translate it for me as a favor, but I turned him down because it seemed like too much to ask someone to do for free.

At some point I suppose I'm going to just have to learn french.

Comment: No, you need to learn how to read math papers in French, a distinctly different business from learning French.  The latter is quite difficult; the former isn't so bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/has-deligne-rapoport-been-translated